# convert dynamic key fields in JSON

Tags: haskell, aeson

here is my JSON structure, there are N records that has a `name` as ID to represent a children

```
{"Kids":
  {"Jack":{"age":10}
  ,"Jane":{"age":9} 
  , .......
  }
}
```

in the data type in Haskell

```
data Kid = Kid { name::String, age::Int}

instance FromJSON Kid where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    ....
```

question is ,how to make the key ( `name` ) as part of the constructor ? the expected output signature is like:

```
decode "input json string" -> [Kid]
```

when the expect decode function was called, it will return a `list` of type `Kid`. Thanks for reading this & appreciate any help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the [`withObject`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.0.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#v:withObject) function, you get access to an [`Object`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.0.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Object) which is actually a [`KeyMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.0.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson-KeyMap.html#t:KeyMap) which you can manipulate much like the usual `Map` from e.g. `containers`. If you're on an older `aeson` version, `Object` will instead be a `HashMap`, so you can use that as well.

EDIT: I remember that `Map` itself also has a `FromJSON`, so you can probably use that instead for a shorter "solution":

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson (FromJSON(..), withObject, (.:), fromJSON)
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data Kid = MkKid {name :: String, age :: Int}

newtype Kids = MkKids {unKids :: [Kid]}

instance FromJSON Kids where
  parseJSON = withObject "Kids" $ \o -> do
    kvmap <- o .: "Kids"
    pure $ MkKids $ map (uncurry MkKid) $ Map.toList kvmap
```

Old "solution", which manipulates they `KeyMap`

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson.Key (Key)
import qualified Data.Aeson.Key as Key
import qualified Data.Aeson.KeyMap as KeyMap
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser, Object, Value)
import Data.Aeson (FromJSON(..), withObject, (.:), fromJSON)

data Kid = MkKid {name :: String, age :: Int}

newtype Kids = MkKids {unKids :: [Kid]}

instance FromJSON Kids where
  parseJSON = withObject "Kids" $ \o -> do
    inner <- o .: "Kids"
    withObject "inner" parseKids inner
    where
      parseKids :: Object -> Parser Kids
      parseKids obj =
        fmap MkKids $ traverse toKid $ KeyMap.toList obj
      toKid :: (Key, Value) -> Parser Kid
      toKid (k, v) = do
        age <- parseJSON v
        let name = Key.toString k
        pure $ MkKid {name, age}
```